# how to use GetLocalResourceObject inside asp.net mvc views

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Actually I am going from webforms to mvc , In webfroms I use `<%= GetLocalResourceObject("906") %>` in my aspx page inside html to access `LocalResourceObject`. like:

```
<label for="formGroupExampleInput"><%= GetLocalResourceObject("906") %>   </label>
```

I want same thing in asp.net mvc 5 views.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `@HttpContext` like this:

```
@HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(<virtual-path>, <resource-name-key>)
```

for more information see [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1655383.aspx?how%20do%20you%20use%20local%20resources%20with%20MVC%203%20Razor).

**Update1**

For get resource from database and using it in mvc, see [this](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization-store-strings-in-database-or-xml.aspx).

Comment: actually i am getting resourses from database so no virtual path :(

Comment: @TheComputerScientist I added link for getting resources. See this.

Comment: i check the link but its not helpfull for me.

Comment: actually i need @HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(<virtual-path>, <resource-name-key>) without virtual path.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the global and local resource using this syntax:

```
@Resources.[ResourceName].[Property]
```

For example, if you have a Common.resx with `MyLabelText` propery:

```
<label for="formGroupExampleInput">@Resources.Common.MyLabelText</label>
```

**EDIT**
If you're getting them from the database, then how are you using `GetLocalResourceObject`? This is used for xml resources. Are you extending it in your project to get the info from the database? If so, you may try:

```
<label for="formGroupExampleInput">@HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject("906")</label>
```

Comment: actually i am getting resourses from database :(

Comment: You should mention that in your question. See my edit.

Comment: its give me error. No overload method GetLocalResourceObject take 1 argument

Comment: Did you read my edit? In web-forms, you use the `GetLocalResourceObject` which is a member of the `Page` and has only one argument because it gets the first `virtualPath` argument automatically from the resx file that matches the page name. For `HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject` in MVC, you need to pass the name of the resx file in the first argument. I repeat, this is coming from the resx, not db. So if you're saying that you used `GetLocalResourceObject("906")` to get it from db, then your project overrides this function and you need to copy that code to the new MVC project.